# How can I protect a picoammeter or a picoscope in HVDC measurements?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-divider, high-voltage, insulation, hvdc

I'm trying to measure the leakage current along an insulator energize with HVDC (the effect of space charges is been considered).

- Can I connect a picoammeter to the ground electrode? If yes, please how do I protect the picoammeter so as not to damage it?

Or

- Can I connect a voltage divider (with 5kohms and 50ohms connected in series) at the ground electrode, measure the voltage across the 50ohms with a picoscope and from there I can use V=IR to get my current? If yes, please how do I protect the picoscope from getting damaged?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I connect a picoammeter to the ground electrode? If yes, please how do I protect the picoammeter so as not to damage it?

You can't measure amps without connecting an ammeter in series, so I'm not going to make a recommendation on this. If you want to measure current, get a current probe for your picoscope.

> Can I connect a voltage divider (with 5kohms and 50ohms connected in series) at the ground electrode, measure the voltage across the
>   50ohms with a picoscope and from there I can use V=IR to get my
>   current? If yes, please how do I protect the picoscope from getting
>   damaged?

Yes you can use a voltage divider to lower the voltage to a device. If you used a 5k, that might be too low resistance. Lets say your using 200VDC, a 5k resistor will burn up ~8W so it had better be a big resistor rated for 10W or you could use a higher resistance value.

One problem is that most of the picoscopes have a 200k input impedance, which is quite low for a scope, but that will cause a small amount of error depending on the resistors used for the voltage divider.

One way to protect against transients is to use a zener diode, the picoscope can tolerate 50V (so it probably has 50V zener) just to be save you could put one or more zeners on the bridge between 20V and 50V to sink current if it gets outside of the picoscopes range.

You also didn't specify the input voltage or picoscope, so look up the specs for the scope you have.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnZ02o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

250kV????

If you want to monitor high voltage like +100kV then your going to need a big resistor, and it will need to be protected from arcing. Why you ever thought you could do this with a 5k ohm resistor I'll never know (at 250kV that would be up to 12.5MW dissipated in the resistor, it would be toast, assuming that you have a large low impedance source)

You'll need something [like this](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/NRV-100-High-precision-100kV-high_60386171965.html?s=p), a 10000:1 scope probe, and even that will only get you to 200kV because the picoscope will clip at ±20V. I would recommend getting a scope that can handle a wider voltage range as it will probably be more expensive to get a 100000:1 probe if they even make them.

[image]

Comment: Yep, just change the values in the model above.

Comment: If you using 250KV, your going to have to use more than just a voltage divider, normal off the shelf resistors would be fried in a second. Even a 1MΩ resistor will have 62kW of heat produced in it. I don't answer moving target questions

Comment: @Llanre, for a 100kV-250kV test application you would need not just to increase R1, you would need to design a sectional resistor with insulated barriers made of teflon (PTFE) or something, otherwise your probe will likely "flashover" first, and you will have no valid test result at all at very least, or kill yourself (or operator of your equipment). Based on the comments, I strongly recommend you to stop what you are doing, and advise your management to hire a real Certified Professional Engineer for this job. 200 kV is no joke.